can't launch validator node: Failed to start validator: "PoH is slower than cluster target tick rate
trying to start a validator node, getting following error:
Failed to start validator: "PoH is slower than cluster target tick rate! mine: 676597124 cluster: 400000000."
the node itself has 64 cores and 512GB of RAM, can you help me to understand what's missing.
to me 676597124 is bigger than 400000000

The error message is a little bit unclear, and has been improved in v2.0. But in v1.18, it's actually reporting the number of nanoseconds per tick: https://github.com/anza-xyz/agave/blob/6b04e8811190f74ebcd1c95c50fa724c11066dfe/core/src/validator.rs#L1625-L1632
In this case, your machine is taking too long to produce ticks.
